# Github : Can I embed gist with comment?

Tags: github, github-pages, gist

As we know, there is a *Embed* in gist.

> Embed ——Embed this gist in your website.

If we want use it, we should input

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/yourusername/yourgistid.js"></script>
```

but it doesn't have *gist comments*.

Can I ember gist with comment in my website (like github-pages and so on)?

Can I ember my project's issue comment in my website?